# How to fix Storybook a components example endlessly reloads?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, storybook

After updating Storybook from version 6 to 7, when opening the documentation of React stories in Storybook, the component example endlessly reloads. Has anyone encountered this issue?

On the next gif animation you can see that: Documentation of a component is started, but example of component is reloading all time, and I can't look at code example.

[image]

I have a basic configuration of Storybook:

Versions:

```json
{
  "@storybook/addon-actions": "^7.4.6",
  "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.4.6",
  "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.4.6",
  "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.4.6",
  "@storybook/addon-mdx-gfm": "^7.4.6",
  "@storybook/node-logger": "^7.4.6",
  "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^7.4.6",
  "@storybook/react": "^7.4.6",
  "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.4.6"
}
```

Stroybook main.js:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    'storybook-react-i18next',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
    '@storybook/preset-create-react-app',
    '@storybook/addon-mdx-gfm',
  ],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/react-webpack5',
    options: {},
  },
  webpackFinal: (config) => {
    config.resolve.modules.push(process.cwd() + '/node_modules');
    config.resolve.modules.push(process.cwd() + '/src');

    // this is needed for working w/ linked folders
    config.resolve.symlinks = false;
    config.plugins.push(
      // Removing Speedy so the static storybook styling doesn't break
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        SC_DISABLE_SPEEDY: true,
      })
    );
    return config;
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: true,
  },
};
```

Storybook preview.js:

```js
import '../src/core/ui/styles/reset.css';
import i18n from './i18n';

export const parameters = {
  i18n,
  locale: 'en',
  locales: {
    ru: 'Russian',
    en: 'English',
  },
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
  backgrounds: {
    default: 'light',
    values: [
      {
        name: 'light',
        value: '#F4F4F8',
      },
      {
        name: 'dark',
        value: '#1B2431',
      },
      {
        name: 'gray',
        value: '#E5E5E5',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```